# Return an image from a controller action in symfony

Tags: symfony

I need to access an image by providing its name in the url path, i tried to use this code but the image is not showing

```
  /**
 *
 * @Route("images/{imgname}",name="workflow_image")
 */
public function WorkflowImageAction(Request $request,$imgname){



    $filepath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/images/workflow/'.$imgname;

    $file =    readfile($filepath);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type'     => 'image/png',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"');
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Double check how the readfile function works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are serving a static file, you can use a [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

$file = 'path/to/file.txt';
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);

return $response;
```

More info about [Serving Files in Symfony2 in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files).

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, it's a good idea to share image through php?

You can write some rules for folder web/image/workflow in your server (nginx or apache).

Share them through php is bad idea.
Nginx/apache can do it very fast, not using RAM (php read full image in RAM).
Also, nginx/apache can cache this image.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here are outdated.

I would suggest not using `BinaryFileResponse` or using `file_get_contents` since they would read the whole file and place it in your memory.

Please use `StreamedResponse` provided at `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse`.

```
$imageFilePath = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../var/tmp/bean.jpg";
$streamedResponse = new StreamedResponse();
$streamedResponse->headers->set("Content-Type", 'image/png');
$streamedResponse->headers->set("Content-Length", filesize($imageFilePath));

$streamedResponse->setCallback(function() use ($imageFilePath) {
    readfile($imageFilePath);
});

return $streamedResponse;
```